# Using wildcard * between words in ldap_search

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

When I try to make a search in php by means of `ldap_search` using a wildcard between words it always returns an empty array.
The same filter pattern on the Active Directory Administrative Center does return things (and very quickly so its not a problem of performance or lack of resources)

This is the filter pattern:

```
(&(objectClass=computer)(|(dNSHostName=*J*Lopez*)(dNSHostName=*J*Lapuente*)))
```

and this is my complete `ldap_search` call:

```
@ldap_search( $t_ds, 'OU=Computers,DC=gp,DC=int', '(&(objectClass=computer)(|(dNSHostName=*J*Lopez*)(dNSHostName=*J*Lapuente*)))');
```

`$t_ds` is valid ldap link identifier and works perfectly on other function calls.

I can retrieve data from ldap without problem, the only issue is that it seems like `ldap_search` does not like wildcards in between words...

When after the previous `ldap_search` I use `ldap_get_entries` all I get is:

```
array(1) { ["count"]=> int(0) }
```

But when I copy-paste the same filter on Active Directory Administrative Center this is what I get:

[Filter applied on AD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS8Bg.png)

Could it be that wildcards between strings is not supported by `ldap_search`? Am I doing something wrong? Is there any workaround?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Ok, I found the problem myself, was a simple variable naming mistake. Sorry. I'm as dumb as one can be hahaha... Maybe I opened the question to quickly. Sorry again. If any admin sees this question, feel free to delete it...